# Плавное изменение размера границы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, border

Я пытаюсь добиться плавного изменения размера границы, как на картинке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я сомневаюсь, что это возможно сделать с применением только CSS / HTML. Или я ошибаюсь?

Я бы использовал его в качестве фонового изображения, но это решение будет неэффективно, так как будет много элементов с различными размерами.

Есть ли другое решение?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55889836/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вот аппроксимация с использованием некоторого преобразования и перспективы (без прозрачности)

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 20px solid red;
  border-width: 20px 3px 20px 20px;
  border-radius:55px;
  transform:perspective(112px) rotateY(5deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 35px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform: perspective(112px) rotateY(-7deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Этого можно добиться, как с помощью псевдоэлемента, так и с использованием содержимого внутри:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 20px solid red;
  border-width: 20px 3px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  transform: perspective(112px) rotateY(5deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 19%;
  bottom: 10%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 36px;
  transform: perspective(112px) rotateY(-7deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
```

Вот еще одна идея со сложной фоновой окраской с прозрачностью и улучшенным контролем реагирования:

```css
.box {
  max-width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  padding:30px 20px;
  z-index:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:40px;
  background:
    /*gradient position/size*/
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,transparent 23px,red 25px) top left/34px 32px,  
    radial-gradient(circle at top right   ,transparent 23px,red 25px) bottom left/34px 32px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/10px 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top left   ,transparent 45%,red 50%) top left   /85% 10px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 45%,red 50%) bottom left/85% 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(5deg);
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text some text some text some text some text
</div>
<div class="box">
  some text some text
</div>
<div class="box">
  some text text
</div>
<div class="box">
  some text 
  some text 
  some text
</div>
```

Чтобы лучше понять окраску, измените цвет каждого градиента:

```css
.box {
  max-width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  padding:30px 20px;
  z-index:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:40px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,transparent 23px,rgba(200,0,0,0.6) 25px) top left/34px 32px,  
    radial-gradient(circle at top right   ,transparent 23px,rgba(200,0,0,0.6) 25px) bottom left/34px 32px,
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) left/10px 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top left   ,white 45%,green 50%) top left   /85% 10px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,white 45%,black 50%) bottom left/85% 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(5deg);
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text some text some text some text some text
</div>
```